# Python/Mysql - inserting variable values into table

Tags: python, mysql, variables, tuples, sql-insert

error message when trying to insert variable values into table.

> Error: {} Failed executing the operation; Could not process parameters: int(10), it must be of type list, tuple or dict

I have a table called FOODS which contains nutritional values of various foods. I want to extract foods consumed during the day, adjust values by quantity eaten and place result into table called CONSUMED.

`int(10)` in the error statement is the value of `fieldvar0`. When leaving this variable out the error statement stays the same but now refers to "cheese" - the value of fieldvar1.

Herewith code. I'm new to this so probably not very elegant.

```
# procedure to store food consumed to consumed table
sql_select_query = """select id, category, type, \
brand, seller, baseunit, baseqty, kcal, fat, sat_fat, \
carbs, sugar, free_sugar, fibre, protein, salt \
from foods where id = %s"""
cursor.execute (sql_select_query, (id,))
data = cursor.fetchone()
fieldvar0, fieldvar1, fieldvar2 = data[0], data[1], data[2],
fieldvar3, fieldvar4, fieldvar5 = data[3], data[4], data[5],
fieldvar6, fieldvar7, fieldvar8 = data[6], data[7], data[8],
fieldvar9, fieldvar10, fieldvar11 = data[9], data[10], data[11],
fieldvar12, fieldvar13, fieldvar14 = data[12], data[13], data[14],
fieldvar15 = data[15],
# sample check variables obtained from foods table
print (fieldvar0, fieldvar14, fieldvar15)
user_percentage = int(input("Percentage of base quantity consumed? "))
fieldvar7 = fieldvar7*user_percentage/100
#check calculated ok
print (fieldvar7)
# ok to here -  I didn't calculate other fields at this stage while testing
cursor.executemany("insert into consumed(id, category, type, brand,\
seller, baseunit, baseqty, consumed, kcal, fat, sat_fat, \
carbs, sugar, free_sugar, fibre, protein, salt) \
values (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s,%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, \
%s, %s, %s)", (fieldvar0, fieldvar1, fieldvar2, fieldvar3, \
fieldvar4, fieldvar5, fieldvar6, str(user_percentage), \
fieldvar7, fieldvar8, fieldvar9, fieldvar10, \
fieldvar11, fieldvar12, fieldvar13, \
fieldvar14, fieldvar15))
connection.commit()
```

Comment: Whay are you copying this data? Wouldn't it be enough to maintain a list of food IDs in your `consumed` table?

Comment: You don't need to put a backslash at the end of the line when you use triple quotes. The whole point of triple quotes is that you can write multi-line strings without escaping.

Comment: Use `cursor.execute()`, not `cursor.executemany()`. `executemany()` requires the parameters argument to be 2-dimensional, you've given a single tuple.

Comment: There's also no need to use two queries at all. You can use a `SELECT` query as the source of data in `INSERT`.

Comment: Which line causes the error? Presumably `cursor.execute (sql_select_query, (id,))`?

Comment: Thanks - good hints for newbies. Couldn't solve problem so changed approach. Moved all fields for food consumed from  table Foods to table Consumed, then updated  fields in Consumed to reflect quantities actually consumed. This worked.

Comment: Given up - notwithstanding all the examples available cannot insert sum of columns into table. Wanted to use the program for own needs. Have now installed Windows 7 on top of Virtualbox, installed old VisualDbase and got what I want within a week.